# Gridlayout manager with different column numbers in each row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I need a recycler view with different number of columns in a row. For that I have used a gridlayout manager with dynamic span size. Here is my code:

```
rvSubCat.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(4, 1)
        val viewTreeObserver = rvSubCat.getViewTreeObserver()
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener { calculateSize() })
        categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter(categoryList, true, this)
        rvSubCat.adapter = categoryAdapter


 private fun calculateSize() {
        val spanCount = Math.floor((rvSubCat.getWidth() / SizeUtils.dp2px(sColumnWidth.toFloat())).toDouble()).toInt()
        (rvSubCat.getLayoutManager() as StaggeredGridLayoutManager).spanCount = spanCount
    }
```

But the desired result is not good. It is fixing the number of columns in every row. I need the number of columns should depend upon the total width of the row items.

**Need this (Desired Result):**

[image]

**Getting This**

[image]

Comment: I think you should use Tag views library for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best light weight library i use

```
compile 'com.xiaofeng.android:flowlayoutmanager:1.2.3.2'
```

Benifit is you dont need to change your existing code, you just need to change recyclerview's LayoutManager like

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new FlowLayoutManager());
```

You are all set, Happy coding :)

**Update** You know already how to populate recycler view. But verify by following

```
private void setAdapter() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragment_view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new FlowLayoutManager());
    myRecyclerAdapter = new AdapterOrders(getActivity(), list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

Call `myRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after list is change from any source.

Comment: Good solution. But the recycler view got blank :( No data is visible now

Comment: It is working with :         flowLayoutManager.isAutoMeasureEnabled = true

Comment: Great dude, i think this issue happens when your item either height or width is match parent

Answer (score 0):

What you need is flow Layout. I think these library will help you solve the purpose :

https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout
https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Adjusts according to size of texts. Hope this helps !

Comment: Good solution but I have a recycler view to be shown. Can I add a flow layout inside recycler view

Comment: Yes you can , But seeing the image in the question I guess you won't be needing a recycler view , flow layout will handle itself , you just need to add tags dynamically.

Comment: I have updated the answer with another library which I am using in my project .